# Какую функцию выполняет webkit в CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

Я знаю, что есть: `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-ms-`.
Также я знаю, для каких браузеров используются эти ... (группы?)
Но вот если брать пример с `-webkit`, то что конкретно он делает в CSS? Пробовал удалять строчку с `-webkik-` и ничего не менялось.
Например, у меня есть `background: -webkit-linear-gradient` и `background: linear-gradient`
Удаляю тот, что с `-webkit-`'ом и ничего, собственно не происходит.
Прошу, объясните мне наконец-то, КАКУЮ же всё таки **функцию выполняет** `-webkit-` в CSS? Будет ли код **корректно работать** код без `-webkit-`?
В каких случаях **стоит использовать** `-webkit-`?

P.S.
И да, растолкуйте всё на пальцах, ибо я... ну не опытный кароче :)

Comment: Когда изобретают новое CSS-свойство, то обычно сперва реализуют его с вендорными префиксами типа `-webkit`, тестируют, и если всё хорошо, то в новых версиях префикс убирают и всё работает без него. Следовательно, наличие или отсутствие префиксов зависит от того, насколько старые браузеры вы хотите поддерживать

Comment: Хм, то есть если я делаю проект, допустим, чисто для себя. (а пользуюсь я Chrom'ом), то webkit, o,ms и остальные префиксы использовать необязательно?

Comment: Если без префиксов всё работает, то необязательно. Но вот например `-webkit-appearance` работает только с префиксом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коротко говоря -webkit- и прочее это **вендорные префиксы,** для разных браузеров они разные и используются для ого что бы свойства CSS работали в определенных браузерах корректно, если для работы этот префикс не нужен, то он просто игнорируется, как в вашем случае. [Вот неплохая статья](https://itchief.ru/lessons/html-and-css/css-browser-prefixes)

Надеюсь Вам это поможет.

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо :)